How to manipulate bit of JavaScript integer number as a 64 bit unsigned int
I solve problem using JavaScript in leetcode. I try to solve problem no : 2939. I already solve it. My solution is going fails when test case has 64 bit integer number. So I try to find out why it happens.
I notice that, If I try to set a specific bit in big integer number than it give a wrong answer. For example :
let number = 712958946092406;

// try to set first bit
number |= 1;
console.log(number); // -1330076297 wrong answer

The output is wrong. The output is should be 712958946092407. But it's give me wrong answer.
Then I search the internet why it happens, then I know that, JavaScript does not support 64 bit integer, because the native number type is a 64-bit double,giving only 53 bits of integer range.
Other way to solve this problem is use some modules which provide 64 bit integer support like, int64 in nodejs. Online judge does not allowed it.
So other way to solve this problem is, use array. For example :
let number = 712958946092406;

number = number.toString(2).split("");

// set first bit
number[number.length - 1] = "1";
number = parseInt(number.join(""), 2);
console.log(number); // 712958946092407

I can solve this problem using array, But I curious about, is there other way to achieve 64 bit integer support in JavaScript ?

There's the BigInt type in modern JavaScript, but other than that a fairly complicated library is necessary, either one you write yourself or one you import.

The 53 bits things is true enough, but in this case it's even worse: for bitwise operations, a JS Number only handles 32 bits.

// I forget about the BigInt, Thanks.
